# Mule 3.9 how to send form-data to http

Tags: mule, mule-component

in Mule 3.9 environment mule code is having ftp connector to read the file. How to send the same file to another rest api (http connector) in terms of form-data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the data as a Mule attachment (there's a component to do so). The HTTP connector will recognise those attachments and create a form-data request.